# My Recyclerview cannot scroll until getting all the data from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I am here to demonstrate what my problem is

First, my app is using MVVM architecture . 
I have a repository to fetch all list file from firebase storage

```java
fun getRestItem(type : String) : LiveData<ArrayList<eachItem>> {
        val list = ArrayList<eachItem>()
        val listStream = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<eachItem>>()
            storage.child(type).listAll().addOnSuccessListener {
                it.items.forEach { item ->
                    item.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { url ->
                        val eachItem = eachItem(url.toString())
                        list.add(eachItem)
                        listStream.value = list
                    }
                }
            }
        return listStream
    }
```

And viewmodel to get data

```java
fun getItem()  : LiveData<ArrayList<eachItem>> {
        return drawRepository.getRestItem("Item")
    }
```

Finally , the UI observe the data

```java
 model.getItem().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                if (it != null) {
                    val adapter = ItemAdapter()
                    adapter.submitList(it)
                    binding.doilyRecycler.adapter = adapter
                }
            })
```

My adapter is using ListAdapter class .

The problem is while we are fetching the data , the recyclerview (UI) keeps back to the top and cannot be scrolled down , even though I force to scroll down , the view will keep back to the top until all data from storage has been fetched .
I really don't know what the issue here , I have used listAdapter for so many times and I didn't face such a problem before (Maybe It's because the firebase storage (the way I fetch the data) ?). The scrollbar i can see it is changing while the data size becomes bigger and bigger

**I am guessing that the recycerview keep refreshing while new data is comming ...**

Can you guys give me so suggestions ?

*** edit (show my recyclerview xml

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/doilyRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:spanCount="3"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        tools:listitem="@layout/each_item"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using test list data，not from firebase storage，if question still exist then explain firebase storage is work

Comment: thank u for your suggestion , my approch is to make a rest api to retrieve data from storage , that sounds much nicer

Comment: All roads lead to Roma

Answer (score 0):

I simply fixed the problem by wrapping the recyclerview with nestScrollview , it works （But it really lags while scrolling and getting the data at the same time, it is unacceptable).
I don't know really know why the recyclerview scroll behavior like this in this situation .